# Android Lollipop - animated-selector not completing transitions

Tags: android, android-animation

**I have the following animated-selector:**

```
<!-- res/drawable/animated_state.xml -->
<animated-selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/pressed"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/none"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_not_pressed"/>

    <!-- specify a transition -->
    <transition
        android:fromId="@+id/none"
        android:toId="@+id/pressed">
        <animation-list>
            <item
                android:duration="100"
                android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressing1"/>
            <item
                android:duration="100"
                android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressing2"/>
            <item
                android:duration="100"
                android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressing3"/>
        </animation-list>
    </transition>

    <!-- specify a transition -->
    <transition
        android:fromId="@+id/pressed"
        android:toId="@+id/none">
        <animation-list>
            <item
                android:duration="100"
                android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressing2"/>
        </animation-list>
    </transition>
</animated-selector>
```

**Set as a background of a view:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/animated_state"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:text="Press\n&amp;\nWatch"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="Text"
            tools:textColor="#000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I see when I press the view is that the transition starts as expected **button_not_pressed -> button_pressing1 -> button_pressing2 -> button_pressing3** are performed, but I would expect that the final transition would be to **button_pressed** which does not happen.

Also when I remove the `android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"` line, I get an error that the *state must have a drawable* which I guess means that it should have a function...

So does the drawable defined in the state is the final one? or do I have to set the last item in the animation-list to the final state? or am I doing something wrong?